# Karaf unresolved constraint in bundle : !(version>=1.0.0)

Tags: java, apache-karaf, karaf

I just added a new dependencie in my tata-core-provider-servlets pom.xml : "io.jsonwebtoken" in version "0.7.0". I can build my project in Eclipse but when I want to start the bundle in Karaf I have this error:

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Unable to execute command on bundle 758: Unresolved constraint in bundle tata-core-provider-servlets [758]: Unable to resolve 758.0: missing requirement [758.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=io.jsonwebtoken)(version>=0.7.0)(!(version>=1.0.0)))
```

Is there a restriction in Karaf ? Like no dependencies under 1.0.0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some other library in your bundle require version > 1, I guess.

Comment: In the same Bundle? That's weird cause 0.7.0 is the latest